# How to use only one column (dtype = float) to predict labels (which are one hot encoded) in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am making a model that takes in 1 column that is has float values and using it to predict which class that number should fall into. There are 15 classes. For example, if the number is 0.355 it is likely to fall into class 12.

```
# Turn our data into TensorFlow Datasets
sample_train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_df.pos_norm.to_list(), train_labels_one_hot))
sample_test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_df.pos_norm.to_list(), test_labels_one_hot))

inputs = layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.double)
outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(tf.expand_dims(inputs,1)) # create the output layer
model_sample = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs,
                         outputs=outputs,
                         name="sample_model")

# Compile the model
model_sample.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=["accuracy", get_f1])

history_model_sample= model_sample.fit(sample_train_dataset,
                              epochs=50,
                              initial_epoch = 25,
                              validation_data=sample_test_dataset,
                              callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="accuracy", patience = 3)],
                              validation_steps=int(0.1 * len(sample_test_dataset)))# only validate on 10% of batches
```

I am getting this error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'tf.expand_dims_18' (type TFOpLambda).
    
    dim 1 not in the interval [-1, 0]. for '{{node sample_model/tf.expand_dims_18/ExpandDims}} = ExpandDims[T=DT_DOUBLE, Tdim=DT_INT32](sample_model/Cast, sample_model/tf.expand_dims_18/ExpandDims/dim)' with input shapes: [], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'tf.expand_dims_18' (type TFOpLambda):
      • input=tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float64)
      • axis=1
  • name=None
```

`train_df.pos_norm` is one column in a pandas df that has decimal values. `train_labels_one_hot` is a one hot array that has the labels

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the shape as the syntax of [tensorflow.expand_dims](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tensorflow-expand_dims/) mentions :

```
tensorflow.expand_dims( input, axis, name)
```

where

> axis: It defines the index at which dimension should be inserted. If
> input has D dimensions then axis must have value in range  [-(D+1),
> D].

Illustration :

```
# Importing the library
import tensorflow as tf
 
# Initializing the input
x = tf.constant([[2, 3, 6], [4, 8, 15]])
 
# Printing the input
print('x:', x)
 
# Calculating result
res = tf.expand_dims(x, 1)
 
# Printing the result
print('res: ', res)
```